# Installing a package in Python virtualenv still causes it to be installed globally

Tags: python, virtualenv, pip

I installed virtualenv and created a virtual environment called ENV1.

Then I activated the environment by running 'source bin/activate'. I am sure the virtual environment is activated because the command prompt has changed, reflecting the new environment.

Then from that command prompt, I ran 'pip install lpthw.web'. I would have thought this package will get installed somewhere in the ENV1 directory, but instead it got installed in /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/

Is this the correct behavior? Could someone please point out if I am doing something wrong.

Comment: Check which pip you are actually running (`which pip`), also try running `pip -E path-to-your-env install ...`.

Comment: @abbot Thanks, that helped. I realized I had typed 'sudo pip install lpthw.web', and that was using the system pip. Can you post your comment as an answer, so I can approve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check which pip you are actually running (`which pip`), also try running `pip -E path-to-your-env install ...`.

Comment: Remember that -E option was dropped from pip. It should be used as /path/to/env/bin/pip install package